# Exclude CodingKeys that doesn't need to be altered?

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

Say I have a `struct User` model which has many properties in it.

```
struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    // many more properties...
}
```

As you can see above it conforms to `Codable`. Imagine if the `lastName` property is should be encoded/decoded as `secondName` and I would like to keep it as `lastName` at my end, I need to add the `CodingKeys` to the `User` model.

```
struct User: Codable {
    //...
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName = "secondName"
        // all the other cases...
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way to avoid including all the `cases` in `CodingKeys` that have the same value as `rawValue` like the `firstName` in the above example (Feels redundant)? I know if I avoid the `cases` in `CodingKeys` it won't be included while decoding/encoding. But, is there a way I could override this behaviour?

Comment: Let me know If I'm not clear enough or if this is a duplicate I could only find the one's that said how to exclude unnecessary(not required while encoding/decoding) keys.

Comment: you are not participating from last 2 days :p is everything good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *codable* way, but the benefit is questionable.

Create a generic `CodingKey`

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue; self.intValue = nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) { self.stringValue = String(intValue); self.intValue = intValue }
}
```

and add a custom `keyDecodingStrategy`

```
struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age : Int
}

let jsonString = """
{"firstName":"John", "secondName":"Doe", "age": 30}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ keyPath -> CodingKey in
        let key = keyPath.last!
        return key.stringValue == "secondName" ? AnyKey(stringValue:"lastName")! : key
    })
    let result = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This seems more like what needs to be done to achieve what is required. But, feels a bit over-complicated though.

Comment: Indeed it's pretty cumbersome. I just wanted to show that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a feature at this time. But you can take advantage of using computed properties and make the original one `private`.

```
struct User: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    private var secondName: String
    var lastName: String { 
        get { secondName }
        set { secondName = newValue }
    }
}
```

So no need to manual implementing of `CodingKeys` at all and it acts exactly like the way you like. Take a look at their counterparts:

[image: Preview1]

Comment: Using computed property is probably the best choice. As you've said it does act as required.

Comment: I accepting your answer because it's correct. But, I was expecting something more. Don't know what exactly though. LOL!